# How is a prototype defined in memory?

Tags: javascript

my question is very simple for those who know, I'm curious how is the prototype in JS defined in memory, I understand that a class object has a reference to the class, but since prototypes can be any-object, what is it referencing ? how does the reference change every time ?

Comment: So your premise is that each browser has the same JS runtime implementation? Different vendor, different implementation. This question is way too broad.

Comment: Of course it it different in every browser, but I'm sure the concept is very similar, meaning e.g: that there is some function pointer that points to its parents whenever it is looking for a property.
So I'm asking in general, how is this memory handled, who points to who, which objects are involved

Comment: Since we're a bit offtopic, I'd suggest that you ask our friend google for "v8 object handling", there's a few quite nice sites that pop up which might be exactly what you're after. Good luck!